# Different Checkbox groups should write data in textfields

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

My problem is that I have found a solution for one group of checkboxes and shows the selected data in a text field in my dynamic formular.

But I think the line `$('input:checkbox').change((e)` does not make sense if I want to use a different, or new, group of checkboxes.

My idea is that the two different groups of checkboxes get a unique id to handle with them.

The data i want to include in an MariaDB Database.

```
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Entsperrcode:
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                    <script src="inc/jquery-3.7.0.min.js"></script>
                                    <br>
                                    <table border="1"cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><center>1</center></td>
                                            <td><center>2</center></td>
                                            <td><center>3</center></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><input type="checkbox" id="entsperrcodewisch1" value="1"></td>
                                            <td><input type="checkbox" id="entsperrcodewisch2" value="2"></td>
                                            <td><input type="checkbox" id="entsperrcodewisch3" value="3"></td>
                                        </tr>
                                            <td><center>4</center></td>
                                            <td><center>5</center></td>
                                            <td><center>6</center></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><input type="checkbox" id="entsperrcodewisch4" value="4"></td>
                                            <td><input type="checkbox" id="entsperrcodewisch5" value="5"></td>
                                            <td><input type="checkbox" id="entsperrcodewisch6" value="6"></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><center>7</center></td>
                                            <td><center>8</center></td>
                                            <td><center>9</center></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><input type="checkbox" id="entsperrcodewisch7" value="7"></td>
                                            <td><input type="checkbox" id="entsperrcodewisch8" value="8"></td>
                                            <td><input type="checkbox" id="entsperrcodewisch9" value="9"></td>
                                        </tr>
                                </table>
                                    <input type="text" id="selected" name="entsperrcode"/><br><br>


                                    <script>
                                    (function() {
                                    $('input:checkbox').change((e) => {
                                        if ($(e.currentTarget).is(':checked')) {
                                        var curVal = $('#selected').val();
                                        if (curVal) {
                                            $('#selected').val(curVal + '-' + e.currentTarget.value);
                                        } else {

                                            $('#selected').val(e.currentTarget.value);
                                        }
                                        } else {
                                        var curVal = $('#selected').val().split('-');
                                        var filteredVal = curVal.filter(el => el.trim() !== e.currentTarget.value)
                                        $('#selected').val(filteredVal.join('-'));
                                        }
                                    });
                                    })();
                                    </script>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Beschädigungen:
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                    <script src="inc/jquery-3.7.0.min.js"></script>
                                    <br>
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="beschaedingung1" value="Display"><br>
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="beschaedingung2" value="Rückseite"><br>
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="beschaedingung3" value="Rand"><br>

                                    <input type="text" id="beschaedig" name="beschaedig"/><br><br>


                                    <script>
                                    (function() {
                                    $('input:checkbox').change((e) => {
                                        if ($(e.currentTarget).is(':checked')) {
                                        var curVal = $('#beschaedig').val();
                                        if (curVal) {
                                            $('#beschaedig').val(curVal + '-' + e.currentTarget.value);
                                        } else {

                                            $('#beschaedig').val(e.currentTarget.value);
                                        }
                                        } else {
                                        var curVal = $('#beschaedig').val().split('-');
                                        var filteredVal = curVal.filter(el => el.trim() !== e.currentTarget.value)
                                        $('#beschaedig').val(filteredVal.join('-'));
                                        }
                                    });
                                    })();
                                    </script>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
```

Comment: First of all, make it a _proper_ table. You currently got table cells floating around in there that are not part of a table row, that makes no sense to begin with. And you are closing table rows that were not opened.

Comment: Some minor issues: the [`<center>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center) element is deprecated, and should *not* be used (use CSS to center things), any element with an `id` must have a *unique* id (they cannot be re-used).

Comment: Use https://api.jquery.com/parents/ to go up from the checkbox to the `tr` ancestor first, then use `find` to select the checkboxes within that.

Comment: And IDs have to be unique.

Comment: "*...if I want to use a different, or new, group of checkboxes*" - do the check-box `<input>` elements you've shown in your HTML represent *one* "group" or should should there be different "groups" within those nine elements?

Comment: I edited the example @David Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I'd approach this is as below, with explanatory comments in the code:

```js
// simple utility variable and functions to reduce some of the repetitive typing:
const D = document,
  // here we have means of creating an element, and passing various properties
  // to that new element (className, textContent, borderColor...):
  create = (tag, props) => Object.assign(D.createElement(tag), props),
  // an alias for document, and element, querySelector(), which is used
  // depends on the context which is the document by default:
  get = (selector, context = D) => context.querySelector(selector),
  // as above, but an alias for querySelectorAll(), this explicitly returns
  // an Array instead of a NodeList in order to allow for Array methods to be
  // used (map(), filter()...):
  getAll = (selector, context = D) => [...context.querySelectorAll(selector)];

// named function to handle the events on the <input type="checkbox">
// elements, this is bound later using EventTarget.addEventListener();
// this function takes one argument - 'evt', a reference to the Event Object -
// passed from EventTarget.addEventListener():
const checkboxHandler = (evt) => {

    // this is the element to which the event-handling function is bound:
    let changed = evt.currentTarget,
      // the 'output' is the element in which I'll be showing the results,
      // and uses Element.querySelector() to find the first (if any) element
      // matching the selector which is found within the closest ancestor
      // <fieldset> element:
      output = get('.result', changed.closest('fieldset')),
      // this retrieves the delimiter custom property defined in the CSS,
      // whether via the stylesheet or the inline "style" attribute:
      delimiter = window.getComputedStyle(output,null).getPropertyValue("--delimiter"),
      // we retrieve the value of the changed element (removing leading/trailing
      // white-space; this may or may not be necessary depending on your use-case):
      result = changed.value.trim(),
      // here we use a template-literal string to concatenate the various
      // variables together to create an identifier for the created element
      // (an id could be used, given that this is likely to be unique, but I
      // chose to assume that conflicts may happen across the document):
      resultClass = `${changed.name}${delimiter}${result}`,
      // we create a <span> element with the given textContent and className:
      resultWrapper = create('span', {
          textContent: result,
          className: resultClass,
      }),
      // creating another element - an <em> - to wrap the delimiter character:
      delimiterWrapper = create('em', {
      textContent: delimiter,
      className: "delimiter"
    });
    
    // a checkbox may fire the change event both when it's checked or
    // unchecked by the user; therefore we first test to see whether it
    // was checked (this returns a Boolean true or false):
    if (changed.checked) {
      // if it was checked we append both the created <em> element, along
      // with the created <span> element to the output element:
        output.append(delimiterWrapper, resultWrapper);
    } else {
      // or if it was unchecked, we retrieve the existing element via
      // the class we created created earlier and looking within the
      // output element, using the alias (above) of element.querySelector()
      // by passing a context:
    let toRemove = get(`.${resultClass}`, output);
    
    // we then use an Array literal, passing in both the previous element
    // sibling of the element we wish to remove and the element itself:
    [toRemove.previousElementSibling, toRemove]
      // we then use Array.prototype.forEach() to iterate over the Array:
      .forEach(
        // passing in a reference to the current Array element 'el',
        // and removing that element:
        (el) => el.remove()
      );
    }
};
  
// here we selector all checkbox <input> elements in the document, and
// iterate over that Array:
getAll('input[type=checkbox]').forEach(
  // passing in a reference - 'el' - to the current Node of the
  // Array of Nodes, and using EventTargetTarget.addEventListener()
  // to bind the named function checkboxHandler() (note the deliberately
  // missing parentheses) as the event-handler for the 'change' event:
    (el) => el.addEventListener('change', checkboxHandler)
);
```

```css
/* setting a custom property to use later as a basic
   demonstration of how custom properties might be
   used: */
form {
  --labelSize: 3rem;
}

fieldset {
  /* allows us to easily style the <input> elements
     into a grid, tabular-style, format: */
  display: inline grid;
  /* defining the space between adjacent elements: */
  gap: 0.5rem;
  /* defining the size of the various rows: */
  grid-auto-rows: var(--labelSize);
  /* defining the size of the various columns, using
     repeat() to create a number of columns stored in
     the --columnCount custom variable, with a default
     value of 3: */
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--columnCount, 3), var(--labelSize));
}

label {
  border: 1px solid currentColor;
  display: grid;
  padding: 0.25rem;
  text-align: center;
}

/* this moves the <input> children of the <label>
   element after their next sibling element in order
   that the DOM allows for a checked <input> to style
   the following <span>, despite that <span> visually
   appearing before the <input>: */
label > input {
  order: 1;
}

/* styling the adjacent <span> of the checked <input>: */
input:checked + span {
  /* this isn't particularly great example, but serves
     only to demonstrate how the <span> may be styled
     based on the state of the check-box: */
  background-image:
    radial-gradient(
      at 0 0,
      lightskyblue,
      palegreen
    );
  font-weight: bold;
}

.result {
  border: 1px solid currentColor;
  /* using flex layout: */
  display: flex;
  /* shorthand for:
      flex-direction: row;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
     adjust to your preferences: */
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  gap: 0.25rem;
  /* positioning the element so that it
     starts in grid-column: 1 (the first)
     and finishes in grid-column: -1
     (the last) */
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  padding-block: 0.25rem;
  padding-inline: 0.5rem;
}

/* within the JavaScript we add the .result
   elements along with a previous .delimiter
   element, so here we style a .delimiter
   when it's the first child so that it's not
   visible in the document: */
.result .delimiter:first-child {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form action="#">
  <!-- I opted to wrap each "group" of <input> elements within
       a <fieldset> element within a <form>, as your demo didn't
       look tabular (the element choices aren't really important
       changes require only minor adjustments to the JavaScript: -->
  <fieldset>
    <!-- provides a "title" to the grouped <input> elements: -->
    <legend>Group 1</legend>
    <!-- wrapping the <input> within the <label> so that clicking
         either the <input> or the text will update the checked
         state of the <input> and trigger the change event: -->
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="group-1">
      <span class="labelText">1</span>
      <!-- to associate the <input> elements together in their
           "groups" I've taken advantage of the "name"
           attribute in place of the (invalid duplication of
           "id" attributes) -->
      
    </label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="2" name="group-1">
      <span class="labelText">2</span>
      
    </label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="3" name="group-1">
      <span class="labelText">3</span>
      
    </label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="4" name="group-1">
      <span class="labelText">4</span>
      
    </label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="5" name="group-1">
      <span class="labelText">5</span>
      
    </label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="6" name="group-1">
      <span class="labelText">6</span>
      
    </label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="7" name="group-1">
      <span class="labelText">7</span>
      
    </label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="8" name="group-1">
      <span class="labelText">8</span>
      
    </label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="9" name="group-1">
      <span class="labelText">9</span>
      
    </label>
    <output class="result" style="--delimiter: -;"></output>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Group 2</legend>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="group-2">
      <span class="labelText">1</span>
      </label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="2" name="group-2">
      <span class="labelText">2</span>
      
    </label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="3" name="group-2">
      <span class="labelText">3</span>
      
    </label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="4" name="group-2">
      <span class="labelText">4</span>
      
    </label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="5" name="group-2">
      <span class="labelText">5</span>
      
    </label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="6" name="group-2">
      <span class="labelText">6</span>
      
    </label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="7" name="group-2">
      <span class="labelText">7</span>
      
    </label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="8" name="group-2">
      <span class="labelText">8</span>
      
    </label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="9" name="group-2">
      <span class="labelText">9</span>
      
    </label>
    <output class="result" style="--delimiter: -;"></output>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Group 3</legend>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="group-3">
      <span class="labelText">1</span>
      </label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="2" name="group-3">
      <span class="labelText">2</span>
      
    </label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="3" name="group-3">
      <span class="labelText">3</span>
      
    </label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="4" name="group-3">
      <span class="labelText">4</span>
      
    </label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="5" name="group-3">
      <span class="labelText">5</span>
      
    </label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="6" name="group-3">
      <span class="labelText">6</span>
      
    </label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="7" name="group-3">
      <span class="labelText">7</span>
      
    </label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="8" name="group-3">
      <span class="labelText">8</span>
      
    </label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="9" name="group-3">
      <span class="labelText">9</span>
      
    </label>
    <output class="result" style="--delimiter: -;"></output>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Group 4</legend>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="group-4">
      <span class="labelText">1</span>
      </label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="2" name="group-4">
      <span class="labelText">2</span>
      
    </label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="3" name="group-4">
      <span class="labelText">3</span>
      
    </label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="4" name="group-4">
      <span class="labelText">4</span>
      
    </label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="5" name="group-4">
      <span class="labelText">5</span>
      
    </label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="6" name="group-4">
      <span class="labelText">6</span>
      
    </label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="7" name="group-4">
      <span class="labelText">7</span>
      
    </label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="8" name="group-4">
      <span class="labelText">8</span>
      
    </label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="9" name="group-4">
      <span class="labelText">9</span>
      
    </label>
    <output class="result" style="--delimiter: -;"></output>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/618oxbfd/3/).

In response to OP's comment:

> ... but if I change the name `"group-1"` to `"group1[]"` to build an array the code does not reset the numbers.

I've updated the `name` attribute to reflect those requirements, and added a custom `data-*` attribute to from which the selector is derived (purely for simplicity's sakes, as `[` and `]` would have to be escaped in order to be used as part of the selector, which is needlessly complex though still possible of course).

This leads to the following, adjusted code:

```js
console.clear();
const D = document,
  create = (tag, props) => Object.assign(D.createElement(tag), props),
  get = (selector, context = D) => context.querySelector(selector),
  getAll = (selector, context = D) => [...context.querySelectorAll(selector)];

const checkboxHandler = (evt) => {
  let changed = evt.currentTarget,
    output = get('.result', changed.closest('fieldset')),
    delimiter = window.getComputedStyle(output, null).getPropertyValue("--delimiter"),
    result = changed.value.trim(),
    // here we use the Element.dataset API to form the resultClass selector to
    // enable easy removal of the value from the <output>
    resultClass = `${changed.dataset.name}${delimiter}${result}`,
    resultWrapper = create('span', {
      textContent: result,
      className: resultClass,
    }),
    delimiterWrapper = create('em', {
      textContent: delimiter,
      className: "delimiter"
    });

  if (changed.checked) {
    output.append(delimiterWrapper, resultWrapper);
  } else {
    let toRemove = get(`.${resultClass}`, output);
    [toRemove.previousElementSibling, toRemove].forEach((el) => el.remove());
  }
};

getAll('input[type=checkbox]').forEach(
  (el) => el.addEventListener('change', checkboxHandler)
);
```

```css
form {
  --labelSize: 3rem;
}

fieldset {
  --accent: palegreen;
  display: inline grid;
  gap: 0.5rem;
  grid-auto-rows: var(--labelSize);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--columnCount, 3), var(--labelSize));
}

label {
  border: 1px solid currentColor;
  display: grid;
  padding: 0.25rem;
  text-align: center;
}

label input {
  accent-color: var(--accent, unset);
  order: 1;
}

input:checked+span {
  background-image: linear-gradient( 90deg, aqua, var(--accent, transparent));
}

.result {
  border: 1px solid currentColor;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  gap: 0.25rem;
  grid-column: span 3;
  padding-block: 0.25rem;
  padding-inline: 0.5rem;
}

.result .delimiter:first-child {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form action="#">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Group 1</legend>
    <label>
      <!-- adding the "array-indicator" to the "name" attribute,
           and adding an additional data-name custom attribute: -->
      <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="group-1[]" data-name="group-1">
      <span class="labelText">1</span>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="2" name="group-1[]" data-name="group-1">
      <span class="labelText">2</span>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="3" name="group-1[]" data-name="group-1">
      <span class="labelText">3</span>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="4" name="group-1[]" data-name="group-1">
      <span class="labelText">4</span>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="5" name="group-1[]" data-name="group-1">
      <span class="labelText">5</span>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="6" name="group-1[]" data-name="group-1">
      <span class="labelText">6</span>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="7" name="group-1[]" data-name="group-1">
      <span class="labelText">7</span>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="8" name="group-1[]" data-name="group-1">
      <span class="labelText">8</span>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="9" name="group-1[]" data-name="group-1">
      <span class="labelText">9</span>
    </label>
    <output class="result" style="--delimiter: -;"></output>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>Group 2</legend>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="group-2[]" data-name="group-2">
      <span class="labelText">1</span>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="2" name="group-2[]" data-name="group-2">
      <span class="labelText">2</span>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="3" name="group-2[]" data-name="group-2">
      <span class="labelText">3</span>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="4" name="group-2[]" data-name="group-2">
      <span class="labelText">4</span>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="5" name="group-2[]" data-name="group-2">
      <span class="labelText">5</span>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="6" name="group-2[]" data-name="group-2">
      <span class="labelText">6</span>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="7" name="group-2[]" data-name="group-2">
      <span class="labelText">7</span>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="8" name="group-2[]" data-name="group-2">
      <span class="labelText">8</span>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="9" name="group-2[]" data-name="group-2">
      <span class="labelText">9</span>
    </label>
    <output class="result" style="--delimiter: -;"></output>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>Group 3</legend>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="group-3[]" data-name="group-3">
      <span class="labelText">1</span>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="2" name="group-3[]" data-name="group-3">
      <span class="labelText">2</span>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="3" name="group-3[]" data-name="group-3">
      <span class="labelText">3</span>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="4" name="group-3[]" data-name="group-3">
      <span class="labelText">4</span>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="5" name="group-3[]" data-name="group-3">
      <span class="labelText">5</span>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="6" name="group-3[]" data-name="group-3">
      <span class="labelText">6</span>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="7" name="group-3[]" data-name="group-3">
      <span class="labelText">7</span>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="8" name="group-3[]" data-name="group-3">
      <span class="labelText">8</span>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="9" name="group-3[]" data-name="group-3">
      <span class="labelText">9</span>
    </label>
    <output class="result" style="--delimiter: -;"></output>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>Group 4</legend>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="group-4[]" data-name="group-4">
      <span class="labelText">1</span>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="2" name="group-4[]" data-name="group-4">
      <span class="labelText">2</span>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="3" name="group-4[]" data-name="group-4">
      <span class="labelText">3</span>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="4" name="group-4[]" data-name="group-4">
      <span class="labelText">4</span>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="5" name="group-4[]" data-name="group-4">
      <span class="labelText">5</span>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="6" name="group-4[]" data-name="group-4">
      <span class="labelText">6</span>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="7" name="group-4[]" data-name="group-4">
      <span class="labelText">7</span>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="8" name="group-4[]" data-name="group-4">
      <span class="labelText">8</span>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="9" name="group-4[]" data-name="group-4">
      <span class="labelText">9</span>
    </label>
    <output class="result" style="--delimiter: -;"></output>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/618oxbfd/4/).

References:

- CSS:

  - [`background-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image).
  - [CSS custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*).
  - [CSS logical properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_logical_properties).
  - [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display).
  - [`:first-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child).
  - [`gap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap).
  - [`grid-auto-rows`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-rows).
  - [`grid-template-columns`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns).
  - [`linear-gradient()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/linear-gradient).
  - [`order`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order).
  - [`radial-gradient()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/radial-gradient).
  - [`padding`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding).
  - [`padding-block`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding-block).
  - [`padding-inline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding-inline).
  - [`repeat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeat).
  - [`text-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align).
  - [`var()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var).
- JavaScript:

  - [Array literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#array_literals).
  - [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).
  - [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
  - [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
  - [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement).
  - [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
  - [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
  - [`Element.append()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append).
  - [`Element.previousElementSibling()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/previousElementSibling).
  - [`Element.remove()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/remove).
  - [`Element.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector).
  - [`Element.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector).
  - [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
  - [`HTMLElement.dataset` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset).
  - [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).
  - [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Comment: I have to fill an array to put the results on a mariadb database but if i change the name "group-1" to "group1[]" to build an array the code does not reset the numbers. Example: i click on 1, 2, 3 and remove 2 the 2 does not disaper. I think the "[]" is the problem. How to fix? Thanks for your solution :)

Comment: Please see the additional code in the answer. As an aside the requirement that "*[you] have to fill an array to put the results on a mariadb database...to build an array*" is an example of information that would have been very useful in the original question. Would you mind adding that information in order that anyone visiting, or trying to answer, in future is able to see the requirement? That way they may be able to assess if the answers here might be useful to themselves, or incomplete, or less-efficient as time moves on.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with `closest` (https://api.jquery.com/closest/) and `each` (https://api.jquery.com/each/).

In the case of a change, the parent element (`table`) is found. The output field is set as a data attribute in the table (`data-output-id="#output1"`).

```js
$('input:checkbox').change((e) => {
  var parent = e.currentTarget.closest('table');
  var outputId = parent.dataset.outputId;
  if ($(e.currentTarget).is(':checked')) {
    var curVal = $(outputId).val();
    if (curVal) {
      $(outputId).val(curVal + '-' + e.currentTarget.value);
    } else {
      $(outputId).val(e.currentTarget.value);
    }
  } else {
    var curVal = $(outputId).val().split('-');
    var filteredVal = curVal.filter(el => el.trim() !== e.currentTarget.value)
    $(outputId).val(filteredVal.join('-'));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="inc/jquery-3.7.0.min.js"></script>
<br>
<table data-output-id="#output1" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td align="center">1</td>
    <td align="center">2</td>
    <td align="center">3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="2"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="3"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center">4</td>
    <td align="center">5</td>
    <td align="center">6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="4"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="5"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="6"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center">7</td>
    <td align="center">8</td>
    <td align="center">9</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="7"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="8"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="9"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input type="text" id="output1" name="entsperrcode" /><br><br>
<br>
<table data-output-id="#output2" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td align="center">1</td>
    <td align="center">2</td>
    <td align="center">3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="2"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="3"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center">4</td>
    <td align="center">5</td>
    <td align="center">6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="4"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="5"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="6"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center">7</td>
    <td align="center">8</td>
    <td align="center">9</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="7"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="8"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="9"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input type="text" id="output2" name="entsperrcode" /><br><br>
```

Comment: Ah thx for the help. It runs fine but now i get the problem the selected items comes back in numberic row. Example: i select 1-3-5, than deselect 3 (1-5) and reselect the 3 than 1-3-5 BUT in my first code it was: 1-5-3. How can i be back to 1-5-3? :)

Comment: Why is the javascript wrapped in a `function` that is immediately executed?

Comment: @Tvde1 you are right. I copied it from OP. Updated.